Not receiving email after updating Email in Transactional API event journey
I'm Not receiving any email after updating Email template in the Transactional API event journey.
I followed this article by salesforce https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000396012&type=1 , still no luck. The journey analytics shows that, the email has been sent. But there is no email in the inbox. I tried with different email addresses as well, but failed to receive any email.
Anyone faced this kind of issue?

Have you tried to preview and send the new updated email?

@DucLe Yes, it works well. I was able to do preview and test the new email addresses, I was using to trigger it. I also paused and resumed the journey, still no luck.

Just now, I created a different transactional API even journey and it worked fine and I received an email.
